# ZED camera stream Opencv capture then send to RTSP server

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I am using Opencv to capture the stream from a ZED camera and display it using cv2.imshow.
But I am having issues resending the ZED stream back out as a RTSP stream.
Now the reason I am using Opencv is because I need to extract data from the stream before it is sent out as a RTSP stream.

Here is the code for the Zed camera OpenCV stream capture:

```
def main() :

    # Create a ZED camera object
    zed = sl.Camera()

    # Set configuration parameters
    input_type = sl.InputType()
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2 :
        input_type.set_from_svo_file(sys.argv[1])
    init = sl.InitParameters(input_t=input_type)
    init.camera_resolution = sl.RESOLUTION.HD1080
    init.depth_mode = sl.DEPTH_MODE.ULTRA
    init.coordinate_units = sl.UNIT.METER

    # Open the camera
    err = zed.open(init)
    if err != sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS :
        print(repr(err))
        zed.close()
        exit(1)


    # Set runtime parameters after opening the camera
    runtime = sl.RuntimeParameters()
    runtime.sensing_mode = sl.SENSING_MODE.FILL
    # Setting the depth confidence parameters
    runtime.confidence_threshold = 100
    runtime.textureness_confidence_threshold = 100

    # Prepare new image size to retrieve half-resolution images
    image_size = zed.get_camera_information().camera_resolution
    image_size.width = image_size.width /2
    image_size.height = image_size.height /2

    # Declare your sl.Mat matrices
    image_zed = sl.Mat(image_size.width, image_size.height, sl.MAT_TYPE.U8_C4)
    point_cloud = sl.Mat()


    key = ' '
    while key != 113 :
        err = zed.grab(runtime)
        def click_event (event, x, y, flags, param):
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                # Retrieve the left image, depth image in the half-resolution
                zed.retrieve_image(image_zed, sl.VIEW.LEFT, sl.MEM.CPU, image_size)
                # Retrieve the RGBA point cloud in half resolution
                zed.retrieve_measure(point_cloud, sl.MEASURE.XYZRGBA, sl.MEM.CPU, image_size)
            
                err, point_cloud_value = point_cloud.get_value(x, y)

                distance = math.sqrt(point_cloud_value[0] * point_cloud_value[0] +
                                     point_cloud_value[1] * point_cloud_value[1] +
                                     point_cloud_value[2] * point_cloud_value[2])
                                                     
                print("Distance to Camera at ({}, {}) (image center): {:1.3} m".format(x, y,  distance))
        
        if err == sl.ERROR_CODE.SUCCESS :
            # Retrieve the left image, depth image in the half-resolution
            zed.retrieve_image(image_zed, sl.VIEW.LEFT, sl.MEM.CPU, image_size)
            # Retrieve the RGBA point cloud in half resolution
            zed.retrieve_measure(point_cloud, sl.MEASURE.XYZRGBA, sl.MEM.CPU, image_size)

            # To recover data from sl.Mat to use it with opencv, use the get_data() method
            # It returns a numpy array that can be used as a matrix with opencv
            image_ocv = image_zed.get_data()
        
            cv2.imshow("Image", image_ocv)     
            cv2.setMouseCallback('Image', click_event)
        
            key = cv2.waitKey(10)


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    zed.close()

    print("\nFINISH")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the code for the RTSP server:
How do I send the captured Opencv cv2.imshow out as a RTSP stream

```
     import gi
     gi.require_version('Gst','1.0')
     gi.require_version('GstVideo','1.0')
     gi.require_version('GstRtspServer','1.0')
     from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo, GstRtspServer

     Gst.init(None)

     mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
     server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
     mounts = server.get_mount_points()

     factory = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory()
     factory.set_launch('( zedsrc stream-type=0 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x- 
     raw,format=YUY2,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc insert- 
     sps-pps=1 idrinterval=1 insert-vui=1 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )')
     #factory.set_launch('(v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! 
     image/jpeg,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! nvjpegdec ! video/x-raw ! nvvidconv ! 
     nvv4l2h264enc ! rtph264ay name=pay0 pt=96)')

     mounts.add_factory('/test', factory)
     server.attach(None)

     print('stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test')
     mainloop.run()
```

Comment: There is no question in your posting. What exactly isnt working? Does your streaming work with different image sources? Where do you try to bring the opencv image to the gstreamer?

Comment: Take some research on appsrc gstreamer module

Comment: The Question is "How do I send the captured Opencv cv2.imshow out as a RTSP stream" .  When Using the bottom section of code I am able to send the ZED camera out as a RTSP stream by using 'zedsrc stream-type=0' in the ' factory.set_launch' pipeline. But I need to do some pre processing of the stream before it is sent out RTSP.  The top and bottom code snippets work just fine on there own. I am looking for a way to combine them So the stream comes in OpenCV and out RTSP.

Comment: Take some research on appsrc gstreamer module

Comment: My goal is to extract the depth data out of the stream before it is sent to a Nvidia deepstream pipeline for processing. I am able to send the ZED camera stream to the deepstream pipeline using the ZED gstreamer commands  but there is now way to extract the point cloud out of the ZED gstreamer pipeline. Hence the need to do pre processing in openCV

Comment: That's fine. Gstreamer can use any image data from any application. Use the gstreamer apprsc module in your rstp server and feed that appsrc with I think an appsink from your opencv piprline. Take some research on those.

Comment: You can also try to setup a gstreamer pipeline with opencv VideoWriter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66030433/issue-with-configuration-of-cv2-videowriter-and-gstreamer

Comment: The link was quit useful   Thanks